# jQuery validator with two mutually exclusive rules

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery validator (http://jqueryvalidation.org) on a form and I have an issue where I need a field to pass any one of two rules to be valid. I'm using a rule like:

```
            ngReplyTo: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true,
            email: true
        }
```

and the form element looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="ngReplyTo" id="ngReplyTo">
```

In this field I need either a phone number or an email address. Is there a way to get the validator to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and posted the query in jQuery forums and got it resolved. 
Posting the link here: [jQuery validation - mutually exclusive + ignore default error messages.](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-mutually-exclusive-validation-want-to-ignore-default-message)

All credits to [kbwood.au](https://forum.jquery.com/user/kbwood.au) from jQuery forums.